# Error message in struts.xml

Tags: struts2

I was trying to write a simple Struts 2 program.

In the `struts.xml` I am getting the error

> The file cannot be validated as there was a connection problem.

My `struts.xml` is

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC 
    "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN"
    "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">


<struts>
     <constant name="struts.devMode" value="false" />
     <action name="hello" 
            class="hello.HelloWorldAction" 
            method="execute">
            <result name="success">/HelloWorld.jsp</result>
     </action>
</struts>
```

JAR files are

```xml
commons-fileupload-1.3.1.jar
commons-io-2.2.jar
commons-logging-1.1.3.jar
commons-logging-api-1.1.jar
freemarker-2.3.19.jar
javassist-3.9.0.GA.jar
ognl-3.0.6.jar
struts2-core-2.3.16.3.jar
xwork-core-2.3.16.3.jar
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot the `<package>` element, and DTD should be 2.3:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>    
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC 
    "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.3//EN"
    "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.3.dtd">
<struts>
    <constant name="struts.devMode" value="false" />
    <package name="default" namespace="/" extends="struts-default"> 
        <action name="hello" 
               class="hello.HelloWorldAction" 
              method="execute">
            <result name="success">/HelloWorld.jsp</result>
        </action>
    </package>
</struts>
```